# Dynamic Textbox Size for Javascript Onclick Results

Tags: javascript, textbox, onclick, format

OK, here's the deal:

I found this bit of code that I would like to use for a button that will generate random quotes. Right now it is set up to do 10-letter words only. I see that it is possible to change that value so the text box can accommodate larger character results. However, is there a way to do this so that the size of the text box after the onclick event is dynamically generated based on the character length of the quote it spits out? And if so, is there a way to make it extend vertically and not only horizontally? When I make it larger now, to accomodate roughly 150 characters, it simply runs off the page. I'm new to JS so any help or direction would be appreciated.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
// Use the following variable to specify 
// the number of random words
var NumberOfWords = 28

var words = new BuildArray(NumberOfWords)

// Use the following variables to 
// define your random words:
words[1] = "czarevitch"
words[2] = "brightwork"
words[3] = "verkrampte"
words[4] = "protectrix"
words[5] = "nudibranch"
words[6] = "grandchild"
words[7] = "newfangled"
words[8] = "flugelhorn"
words[9] = "mythologer"
words[10] = "pluperfect"
words[11] = "jellygraph"
words[12] = "quickthorn"
words[13] = "rottweiler"
words[14] = "technician"
words[15] = "cowpuncher"
words[16] = "middlebrow"
words[17] = "jackhammer"
words[18] = "triphthong"
words[19] = "wunderkind"
words[20] = "dazzlement"
words[21] = "jabberwock"
words[22] = "witchcraft"
words[23] = "pawnbroker"
words[24] = "thumbprint"
words[25] = "motorcycle"
words[26] = "cryptogram"
words[27] = "torchlight"
words[28] = "bankruptcy"

function BuildArray(size){
    this.length = size
    for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++){
        this[i] = null}
    return this
}

function PickRandomWord(frm) {
    // Generate a random number between 1 and NumberOfWords
    var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfWords)

    // Display the word inside the text box
    frm.WordBox.value = words[rnd]
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>

<body>

    <FORM NAME="WordForm">
    <INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=10 NAME="WordBox"><BR>
    <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON onClick="PickRandomWord(document.WordForm)" 
    VALUE="Refresh">
    </FORM>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you would do in css.  Try something like this.

```
<FORM NAME="WordForm" style="max-width:50px; overflow-y: scroll;">
```